# Highstock custom datagrouping datetimelabelformats timeseries

Tags: highcharts

I want to use https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.dateTimeLabelFormats

to specify the tooltips for my datagroupings. But when I group a timeseries of 1-minute data in 15 minutes, I have data points of 00:00, 00:01, ..., 00:14 that will be grouped.

My label is now 00:00-00:14, but it makes more sense to display this as 00:00-00:15. How can I achieve this customization of the format of these timegroups?

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping

Comment: But could you reproduce your attempt of setting the dateTimeLabelFormats? Here is a template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c20anu3b/

Comment: I don't have any attempt, I can't find a solution how I can change the label in this example at all, besides the standard (HH:mm adjustments)? I need to increase the value

Comment: You mentioned: My label is now 00:00-00:14, but it makes more sense to display this as 00:00-00:15 - could you reproduce it? I want to see how have you achieve it.

Comment: In the example of data-grouping in highcharts.com/stock it is grouped by hour and it shows a label of 00:00 - 00:59. I would like this to be 00:00 - 01:00

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for more information and clarification for the case. It is impossible to change it from the API options because in the core code this 1 minute is subtracted from the end value.

```
if (xDateFormatEnd) {
    formattedKey += time.dateFormat(xDateFormatEnd, labelConfig.key + currentDataGrouping.totalRange - 1);
}
```

Reassigning this method without this subtracting works as you expect: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ba6qe9o4/